How to make Matching Algorithm more efficent in Python
I've developed a Python script to calculate match scores between users based on their locations. The script generates combinations of users, calculates the average weight for each combination, computes the standard deviation of weights, and finally assigns a score to each combination. However, as the number of users increases, the script's performance becomes noticeably slower.
import random
import statistics

def comb(arr):
    if len(arr) == 2:
        yield [arr]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        first = [arr[0], arr[i]]
        rest = [x for j, x in enumerate(arr) if j != 0 and j != i]
        for com in comb(rest):
            yield [first] + com

def calculate_weight(combination):
    location_1 = combination[0]['location']
    location_2 = combination[1]['location']
    weight = location_weights.get((location_1, location_2), 0)
    if weight == 0:
        weight = location_weights.get((location_2, location_1), 0)
    return weight


location_weights = {('A', 'A'): 1, ('B', 'B'): 1, ('C', 'C'): 1, ('A', 'B'): 0.3, ('B', 'C'): 0.7, ('A', 'C'): 0.5}


locations = ['A', 'B', 'C']
users = []
# Generate users with random locations
for i in range(0, 4):
    new_user = {
        'name': f'User{i}',
        'location': random.choice(locations)
    }
    users.append(new_user)

combinations = comb(users)
matches = []

for i, combination in enumerate(combinations):

    weights = []
    for pot_match in combination:
        weights.append(calculate_weight(pot_match))

    average = sum(weights) / len(weights)
    stdev = statistics.stdev(weights)

    matches.append({
        'users': combination,
        'average': average,
        'stdev': stdev,
        'score': average/(100+stdev)
    })


matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)

for m in matches:
    print(m)

I'm seeking advice on how to optimize this code for better performance, especially when dealing with a larger number of users, depending on the amount it can take seconds up to multiple hours. Is there a way or should i completely change my approach.
I am a beginner programmer, when you find some other mistakes or have optimization suggestions, feel free to tell them.

If your concern is with performance, It would be worth learning another language! Python happens to be one of the slowest languages ever created. However, you can get pretty far by using numpy and other such libraries

How many "users" causes this to run for hours?

The number of ways to partition a collection of 2 users into  pairs is 1*3*5*7*...*(2−1), which is exponential. There is no way around it. If you have 40 users, the number of these pairings is about the number of bytes stored on the whole internet (in 2024). For 104 users, you've reached the estimated number of atoms in the observable universe.

@SIGHUP i don't have the excact numbers, but with 4 users it only takes couple of seconds with 14 users it takes up to 2 min and with 20 users it takes over 10min and i plan to use it for 50-100 users.

@trincot thanks for calculating that, so your saying i should take an other approach, and if so do you have suggestions?

This is not a matter of approach, but to change the target of what output you want to generate. To be clear, if users has 40 entries, your matches list will get 3*10^23 entries, which is just not realistic. You'll have to redefine what you expect as output for such input.

If you just wanted a minimum score - with score just being the sum of weights - "assignment" of users (each user being assigned to exactly one other user), this would be just an assignment problem, which could be solved in O(n³). I can't make much sense of your score formula: The larger the standard deviation is, the larger the average may be?

@trincot alright i, try to modify the output i want to generate.

@Luatic I plan to use other factors that increase or decrease the weight of the match, like age for example. the plan is that the algorithm scores the matches according to how high the avarage weight is but also that it considers the stdev.
for example i have 4 Users:
A-B weight(2) /C-D weight(1)
A-C(4)/B-D(1)
A-D(2.5)/B-C(2.5)
even tho the second and third match group have the same average weight it will take the thrid one because its stdev is lower.

Depending on how you want to score you can use buckets. E.g. Users get placed in a location bucket. Now you only need to compare with Neighboring buckets only and can speedup the compares.

Since the only thing that contributes to their weights is the location, you could prune a vast majority of equivalent matchings. Just track what location pairs you've already generated, and skip redundant ones as they are encountered. This is easy if you rewrite your recursion to pass an accumulator value of "prefix" location pairs (just like you're trying to optimize the tail call recursion).

I don't know your full problem. But others are right. You don't need to find ways to speed up your current approach. You need to find a feasible approach. Storing this for every possible combination is simply not computationally feasible for more than a handful of users.
